# I want to connect an angular 6 front end to a java servlet

Tags: java, angular, servlets

here i need to send the data from an angular 6 front end to a java servlet. I need to know that is there any Directory structure for the same. Now i am attaching my codes

**app.component.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="welcome" method="get">
      Enter your name<input type="text" name="name"><br>
      <button (click)="getValue()">Get Version</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  getValue(){
    this.testService.getData("abc");
  }

}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  public getData(num: String) {
    return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/first/welcome",num);
  }
}
```

**hello.java (Servlet)**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Hello() {}
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String sid=request.getParameter("num");
         System.out.println(sid);
        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<h3>Hello Servlet</h3>");
        out.print("</body></html>");
    }

}
```

This code is not working at all.

if there any solution for this...

here the value of sid is showing as null

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're probably better of returning JSON instead of HTML if you want to use it with Angular

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you

Comment: Your java servlet is sending back HTML. You may find it easier if you return JSON. Angular's HTTPClient expects JSON by default.

Comment: Here my intention is not to send back html back to angular but here the servlet will show a new html page displaying "Hello servlet", on the console of this page i need to display the value of sid that i am passing from the angular project

Answer (score 0):

In your Service you have to map your response to receive the data. Like this for a JSON Response:

```
getValue(){
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/first/welcome",num, options )
   .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And in your Component you have to subscribe to this:

```
getValue(){
  this.testService.getData("abc")
   .subscribe(
    response => {
      //do something with the response
    });

}
```

And:  I would not return HTML form the server. Write it in your Component and and only return the needed values from the server and show them on the client side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But here when i call the http request in angular "this.httpClient.post();" in service.ts, the request is not going into the servlet page. Here i need to send the string "abc" from angular to the servlet page

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my answer. with this service method the server should receive your post.

Comment: when i made this change there occurs an error                                         [ts]
Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
let options: RequestOptions